# ¿Por qué los modales de bootstrap se juntan?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid div-1">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3 font-size-35 div-1 text-align-center">Admin Options</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-md-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal">Add</button>
            <?php if($_SESSION["rank"] === "admin"){
                include '../php/admin/modals/add-p.php';
            } ?>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-md-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DelteModal">Delte</button>
            <?php if($_SESSION["rank"] === "admin"){
                include '../php/admin/modals/delte-p.php';
            } ?>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-md-3" data-toggle="
            modal" data-target="#ViewModal">View</button>
            <?php if($_SESSION["rank"] === "admin"){
                include '../php/admin/modals/ViewGeneral-p.php';
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando abro la página solo aparece el primer botón y los demás no; al abrirlo aparece a un lado el botón número 2 y al darle click aparece el botón 3, pero necesito que se muestren con su respectivo botón.

aquí los modales:

#### Modal Número 1

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add a Product</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="../php/admin/product/add.php" method="post" role="form" name="add-p">
                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control text-color-black col-md-6">
                <br>
                <input type="textarea" name="d" placeholder="Description" class="form-control col-md-6" rows="3">
                <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Modal Número 2

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DelteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="DelteModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delte a Product</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="../php/admin/product/delte.php" method="post" role="form" name="delte-p">
                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control text-color-black col-md-6">
                <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delte</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Modal Número 3

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ViewModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">View General Data</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="../php/admin/view.php" method="post" role="form" name="view">
                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Product" class="form-control text-color-black col-md-6">
                <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">View Data</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te falta una `</div>` que se corresponda con `modal-body`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como te comentaba te falta un `</div>` en `modal-body`.

[Muestra](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/28359/)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ViewModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">View General Data</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="../php/admin/view.php" method="post" role="form" name="view">
                <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Product" class="form-control text-color-black col-md-6">
                <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">View Data</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya funciona, gracias.

Comment: @Fenix Que bien :D